# Laravel where on multiple collections at once

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I'd like to ask whether is possible to use where method on multiple collections at once.. better to say, is possible to symplify this code somehow, please? Thank you so much.

```
$posts_per_weeks = array();

for($i = 10; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $my_posts = $user->posts()
        ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek($i))
        ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subWeek($i-1))
        ->count();
    $all_posts = Post::all()
        ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek($i))
        ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subWeek($i-1))
        ->count();
    array_push($posts_per_weeks, [$my_posts, $all_posts - $my_posts]);
}
```

Method posts() looks like this:

```
public function posts()
{
    if($this->hasAnyRole('broker|super-agent')) {
        $posts = $this->teams()->get()->map(function ($team) {
            return $team->posts->all();
        });
        if($this->hasRole('broker')) {
            $posts->push($this->hasMany('App\Post', 'broker_id')->get());
        }
        return $posts->collapse()->unique();
    } elseif($this->hasRole('admin')) {
        return Post::all();
    } else {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'agent_id')->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: I wanna create stats representing number of user's posts out of all posts and because of chart feature, it's necessary to have `$all_posts` only as a rest number of posts (all posts =- user's post). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [QueryScopes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#local-scopes).

Post.php

```
class Post
{
    public function scopeFromWeek($query, $week) {
        return $builder->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek($week))
                       ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subWeek($week-1));
    }
}
```

In your controller (or wherever you use this code)

```
$posts_per_weeks = [];

for($i = 10; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $my_posts = $user->posts()->fromWeek($i)->count();
    $all_posts = Post::fromWeek($i)->count();
    array_push($posts_per_weeks, [$my_posts, $all_posts - $my_posts]);
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but showing an error - **Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::fromWeek does not exist.**.

Comment: Edited my answer. Removed the `all()` from `Post::all()`, since `all()` returns a collection.

Comment: I think problem is with the first part - `$my_posts`. There's collection too.

Comment: How does the `posts()` method in `User` looks like?

Comment: Please update your question and add the method there. Images are not searchable.

Comment: Done, see it above.

Comment: You are hiding a lot of functionality in your `posts()` method, which is not "guessable" from the name. If you like to stick to Laravel concepts this method just defines the relationship between User and Posts. Everything else has to be done in other ways.

Comment: I see it's quite strange.. but user can have posts whether are its own or are from its team... Think about posts like clients. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy`to group the results

```
$maxWeeksBack = 10;
$myPostCount = $user->posts()->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek($maxWeeksBack))
    ->select('id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('WEEK(created_at)'))
    ->get();

$postCount = Post::where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek($maxWeeksBack))
    ->select('id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('WEEK(created_at)'))
    ->get();
```

This returns the count of posts and myposts as an array, sorted by week. You would need to merge the two arrays to have your array, but this is a much cleaner approach to get the count of the posts.

DISCLAMER: Haven't tested it live, but it should work